# Determine If The Following Set of Vectors Spans $\Bbb R^4$

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the following matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
      1 & 0& 1 & 0 \\
     -1 &-1 &0&  0 \\
      1 &-1& 0 &-1 \\
     -1 & 0& 1 &-1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
And I want to know if the associated set of vectors spans $\Bbb R^4$.

I took $\det(A)$ and got $-4$. Does this mean because the matrices determinant
is not non-zero, that the set of vectors spans $\mathbb R^4$?

Comment: There is a theorem stating that if a linear function $f$ satisfies that its determinant is non zero, then for every basis $(b_\alpha)$ the family $(f(b_\alpha))$ is also a basis. Hence, yes.

Comment: Please type the question when feasible, as here.  Nobody wants to keep flipping back between the image and the question to see the relation between the vectors and the matrix.

Comment: Sorry, this was my first time ever posting

Comment: Can someone fix the dollar that I forgot please 

Answer (score 2):

The determinant is non-zero implies that the vectors are linearly independent. Thus we have a set consisting of 4 linearly independent vectors in a vector space of dimension 4, thus the collection is a basis and in particular spans $\Bbb R^4$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the determinant is nonzero if and only if the columns of your matrix are linearly independent.

Suppose you could find a set of four linearly independent vectors that don't span $\mathbb{R}^4$. We know that a basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$ has four vectors (take the standard basis). Then by the replacement theorem, adding another vector which is not in the span of your vectors will make them linearly dependent, a contradiction since the new vector was not in the span of the others.

So any set of four linearly independent vectors will span $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to think from linear transformation point of view. The determinant of a matrix indicates how a unit volume will be scaled up or down after the linear transformation. If det is $0$, it means this transformation collapse this unit volume into a lower dimension. In this case, det is non-zero. So the unit volume does not collapse. Therefore this linear transformation spans $\Bbb R^4$